# Как присвоить порядковый номер в DataFrame столбцам (комбинаторика)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, комбинаторика

Чтобы точно и понятно объяснить, что мне нужно, приведу пример последовательности действий:

1. Есть DataFrame (в реале же их намного больше):

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'C': [9, 10, 11, 12], 'D': [13, 14, 15, 16], 'E': [17, 18, 19, 20],  'F': [21, 22, 23, 24], 'G': [25, 26, 27, 28], 'H': [29, 30, 31, 32], 'L': [33, 34, 35, 36], 'K': [37, 38, 39, 40], 'M': [41, 42, 43, 44], 'P': [45, 46, 47, 48]})
   df

      A  B   C   D   E   F   G   H   L   K   M   P
   0  1  5   9  13  17  21  25  29  33  37  41  45
   1  2  6  10  14  18  22  26  30  34  38  42  46
   2  3  7  11  15  19  23  27  31  35  39  43  47
   3  4  8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44  48
   ```
2. Делаю комбинаторику с помощью `itertools.combinations` и получаю суммы столбцов:

   ```
   my_list=[(pd.Series(df.loc[:,list(i)].sum(axis=1),\
   name='_'.join(df.loc[:,list(i)].columns))) for i in list(itertools.combinations(df.columns,2))]    
   final_df=pd.concat(my_list,axis=1)
   print(final_df)

        A_B  A_C  A_D  A_E  A_F  A_G  A_H  ...  H_P  L_K  L_M  L_P  K_M  K_P  M_P
    0    6   10   14   18   22   26   30  ...   74   70   74   78   78   82   86
    1    8   12   16   20   24   28   32  ...   76   72   76   80   80   84   88
    2   10   14   18   22   26   30   34  ...   78   74   78   82   82   86   90
    3   12   16   20   24   28   32   36  ...   80   76   80   84   84   88   92
   ```
3. Вот на этом шаге вопросы. Как мне получить вот такой вот, назову его, `df_name_serial_number`?

   а) в столбце 'name' находятся имена столбцов `df` из шага (2.Делаю комбинаторику).
   б) в столбце 'serial_number1' эта порядковый номер из `df` на шаге (1.есть DataFrame).
   в) в столбце 'serial_number2' эта порядковый номер из df на шаге (1.есть DataFrame).
   Другими словами, `A_B` их порядковые номера из шага #1, у 'A'порядковый номер 0, а у 'B' порядковый номер 1. и т.д.

   ```
       name  serial_number1  serial_number2
   0   A_B               0               1
   1   A_C               0               2
   2   A_D               0               3
   3   A_E               0               4
   4   A_F               0               5
   5   A_G               0               6
   6   A_H               0               7
   7   A_L               0               8
   8   A_K               0               9
   9   A_M               0              10
   10  A_P               0              11
   11  B_C               1               2
   12  B_D               1               3
   13  B_E               1               4
   14  B_F               1               5
   15  B_G               1               6
   16  B_H               1               7
   17  B_L               1               8
   18  B_K               1               9
   19  B_M               1              10
   20  B_P               1              11
   21  C_D               2               3
   22  C_E               2               4
   23  C_F               2               5
   24  C_G               2               6
   25  C_H               2               7
   26  C_L               2               8
   27  C_K               2               9
   28  C_M               2              10
   29  C_P               2              11
   30  D_E               3               4
   31  D_F               3               5
   32  D_G               3               6
   33  D_H               3               7
   34  D_L               3               8
   35  D_K               3               9
   36  D_M               3              10
   37  D_P               3              11
   38  E_F               4               5
   39  E_G               4               6
   40  E_H               4               7
   41  E_L               4               8
   42  E_K               4               9
   43  E_M               4              10
   44  E_P               4              11
   45  F_G               5               6
   46  F_H               5               7
   47  F_L               5               8
   48  F_K               5               9
   49  F_M               5              10
   50  F_P               5              11
   51  G_H               6               7
   52  G_L               6               8
   53  G_K               6               9
   54  G_M               6              10
   55  G_P               6              11
   56  H_L               7               8
   57  H_K               7               9
   58  H_M               7              10
   59  H_P               7              11
   60  L_K               8               9
   61  L_M               8              10
   62  L_P               8              11
   63  K_M               9              10
   64  K_P               9              11
   65  M_P              10              11
   ```
4. Второй вопрос - как из полученного `df_name_serial_number` начиная сверху (!) убрать все повторяющиеся название? Чтобы получилось так:

   ```
   df_name_serial_number

       name  serial_number1  serial_number2
   0   A_B               0               1
   21  C_D               2               3
   38  E_F               4               5
   51  G_H               6               7
   60  L_K               8               9
   65  M_P              10              11
   ```

Comment: Конечная цель - получить `df_name_serial_number`? Или `final_df` - тоже нужен?

Comment: 'final_df ' я создаю сам,  нужен 'df_name_serial_number'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 3)

```
cols = df.columns.to_list()

nums = list(range(len(cols)))

res = pd.DataFrame(
        [[f"{cols[a]}_{cols[b]}", a, b] for a, b in list(combinations(nums, 2))], 
        columns="name serial_number1 serial_number2".split())
```

---

```
In [63]: res
Out[63]:
   name  serial_number1  serial_number2
0   A_B               0               1
1   A_C               0               2
2   A_D               0               3
3   A_E               0               4
4   A_F               0               5
..  ...             ...             ...
61  L_M               8              10
62  L_P               8              11
63  K_M               9              10
64  K_P               9              11
65  M_P              10              11

[66 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

### 4)

```
df_name_serial_number = \
    pd.DataFrame([[f"{cols[i-1]}_{cols[i]}", i-1, i] for i in range(1, len(cols), 2)],
                 columns=["name", "serial_number1", "serial_number2"])
```

---

```
In [65]: df_name_serial_number
Out[65]:
  name  serial_number1  serial_number2
0  A_B               0               1
1  C_D               2               3
2  E_F               4               5
3  G_H               6               7
4  L_K               8               9
5  M_P              10              11
```

Comment: отлично! эта сразу 4ый шаг, но мне шаг 3 еще нужен что бы я мог делать.

Comment: Спасибо Вам ! " MaxU "

Comment: 4-ый шаг не совсем то что в задании, результат конечный тот, НО надо получить его другим способом. Нужно делать ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО с начало получаем df_name_serial_number в данном решении от (MaxU  спасибо!)  это `res`  , потом из полученного `res`  нужно НАЙТИ УНИКАЛЬНЫЕ значения начиная сверху (!)  именно убрать все повторяющиеся название(значения) и результат будет точно таким же как представил MaxU, только другим способом.

Comment: @VEL, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814). Кстати [по правилам SO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3169/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc) вопрос должен содержать один вопрос, поэтому лучше открыть новый вопрос

Comment: @VEL, если вам доступен список столбцов исходного фрейма, то проще и быстрее получить его тем способом, который я указал в ответе

Comment: (@VEL, если вам доступен список столбцов исходного фрейма,) - Исходный фрейм теряет свою актуальность после второго шага, так как на третьем шаге получаем фрейм с которым будут проводиться манипуляции(перетасовка) и потом надо начиная сверху фрейма оставить только все уникальные значения. В примере показано все в простой форме. Спасибо Вам MaxU за ответ по третьему шагу.  И раз нельзя задавать два вопроса в одном, тогда открою новый вопрос по четвертому шагу.